# In single select statement count number of orders within several time ranges

Tags: sql, t-sql, date, count

Thanks in advance for any thoughts, advice, and suggestions!

System: SQL Server 2008 R2

I need to count for a given customer the number of repurchases within several different time intervals (date ranges), and display these counts in a single table.  I get this working with several subsequent common table expressions (cte) which I finally join together. This way, however, is cumbersome and rather inefficient (in terms of performance speed).

The SQL code I expected to be shortest and fastest, however, does not work for several reasons and will return error messages like 
“ the subqueries (Select (count …….)  will return several values and hence “cannot be used as an expression” 
or
Another error message is:  “An aggregate may not appear in the WHERE clause unless it is in a subquery contained in a HAVING clause or a select list, and the column being aggregated is an outer reference.”
Please find below a sample table (WDB), the desired result table (WDB_result) and the SQL code that need improvement. Thanks a lot to everyone who may help!

Sample WDB Table:

[image]

- CustomerID: customer ID
- InNo: invoice number
- OrderDate: order date

Result table WDB_result:

[image]

Columns

> A) total number of repurchases
>   B) number of repurchases within the first 3 months
>   C) number of repurchases within the first 6 months
>   D) number of repurchases within the first 12 months
>   E) number of repurchases with last 3 months
>   F) number of repurchases with last 6 months
>   G) number of repurchases with last 12 months

Sample SQL Code to calculate columns A, B, und E:

```
SELECT 
CustomerID
, COUNT(InNo) OVER (PARTITION by CustomerID) -1) as Norepurchases_Total
, (SELECT (COUNT(InNo) OVER (PARTITION by CustomerID) -1)  as Count3
    FROM WDB 
    WHERE OrderDate between MIN(OrderDate) and DATEADD(month, 3, MIN(OrderDate))
       ) as Norepurchases_1st_3months
 , (SELECT (COUNT(InNo) OVER (PARTITION by CustomerID) -1)  as Count3
    FROM WDB 
    WHERE OrderDate between MAX(OrderDate) and DATEPART(y, DATEADD(m, -3, getdate()))
       ) as NoRepurchases_Last_3months
FROM WDB;
```

Answer (score 0):

Typically what I would do in a situation like this is something like

```
SELECT  CustormerID,
        SUM(
            CASE
                WHEN OrderDate > @ThreeMonthsAgo AND OrderDate <= @CurrentDate
                    1
                ELSE 0
            END
           ) InLast3Months,        
        SUM(
            CASE
                WHEN OrderDate > @SixMonthsAgo AND OrderDate <= @ThreeMonthsAgo 
                    1
                ELSE 0
            END
           ) InLast3To6Months,
        ...
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY CustomerID
```

This will alow you to determine the buckets beforehand as variables, as shown, and then count how many items falls in which buckets.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very interesting query and I think what you're after can be achieved if you read over this stackoverflow article on [multiple aggregate functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1269639/multiple-counts-within-a-single-sql-query?rq=1).

Applying the same concept as is used in this question should solve your problem.